# React Native App with Expo and Braintree Integration

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, braintree

I've built about 80% of an app for my company. the issue I'm running into is I'm not sure where to aim my efforts now.

I need to integrate Braintree into the application for payment processing (We already have a highly trafficked website that uses it). However it seems the only way to facilitate that integration is by using build.gradle files for android and pod files for ios.

I'm wondering if there is something I'm missing here for their integration and if there is another route I can take to support it.

Seems like a lot to have to do to integrate one sdk, I was hoping you someone could explain the process to me or at least what I need to learn and consider on my own. I feel like there is not a lot of supporting docs to integrate things like this into a project that's using expo and already so far along.

Any advice would be appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my current project we've managed to implement the changes required to add the popupbridge without ejecting the whole project. Currently It's still not adding popupbridge to the window object, but I'm working on it.

Expo gives you various tools to manipulate the sourcecode of the native build directories ios and android. At this point I can only tell you about the iOS part.

Basically what we have to do is tell expo to manipulate the Appdelegate and Podfile according to the popupbridge guide using the config plugins.

https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/

another very helpful resource:
https://www.sitepen.com/blog/doing-more-with-expo-using-custom-native-code

I'll keep you updated about the progress.

Comment: How did you get on with this? We want to do the same thing now in 2022 :)